# Muli-line button in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, button

I'm currently in a horrible situation that requires me to style an input of type "button" over two lines. Having a fixed width on the button causes the text within the button to wrap onto two lines in all other browsers except IE.

My question is therefore, how do I specify that an input with value="Button to Wrap" wraps onto two lines in IE?

I'm willing to accept any hacks or workarounds to make this happen.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`button` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON)  instead - it can contain other markup:

```
<button type="button">
First Line<br />
Second Line<br />
Third Line<br />
</button>
```

Comment: That's only relevant if the `type` attribute is `submit`, but the question refers to an input of type `button`. IE is completely broken even with the `input` element of type `submit` anyway, so as usual, w3schools' information is just wrong enough to be dangerous under certain circumstances.

Comment: It works in IE 8, and so you can feel free to use the <button> tag anywhere you'd like. (IE 7 and before are dead)

Answer (score 3):

What works for me is to set CSS `white-space` to `pre-line` of the button input with a fixed width.

But only the first line will be visible on the button input. So height must be set to a fixed value or to auto.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried hard returns in your source code? Works for me...

```
<p>
<input type='button' value='3
Line
Button'
/>
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, sorry should've said. The value is being passed as a string from a Java variable, so can't do hard returns. Thanks though!

Comment: [I'm willing to accept any hacks or workarounds to make this happen.] -> measure the size of the string, compare to the fixed width you are setting the button to and add \n on the right place

Comment: hm, maybe you could try 
System.getProperty("line.separator");
in stead of \n?

Comment: Interesting, not doing the Java dev myself, so will pass it on. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I tried line.separator and it doesn't work. But the button does.

Answer (score 1):

The word-wrap CSS attribute seems to be the word on this one. If that doesn't work, you'll have to try using a div tag style to look like a button and an onClick handler...

```
<input type=button value="test" style="word-wrap: break-word"></input>
```

This might need position, height and width attributes as well to work.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be working either. Didn't really know about break-word though, thanks for letting me know about it!

Comment: OK, take 2: I put in a windows line break into the text, and it worked. (used the html test on w3schools).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using br tags?

Comment: <br> tags wouldn't work as the break occurs within the value=" " attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to add a child span to the button, set its display to block and limit its width as the button's is.

It only affects IE 8 and 9 when the document is in IE7 mode.

Answer (score -1):

Why not to use image button? Make image for button, and pressed button...
Or make button in flash (: