# Button text won't line break IE11 (Chrome, IE9 fine)

Tags: html, cross-browser, line-breaks

I am trying to force a line break between two words. It works in the latest version of Chrome and IE9. However, it doesn't work in IE11. I want the button to show one word on one line and the other word on another line. For example,

TestTestTest/ 
FooFooFooFoo

I don't want the text to wrap, I want to force the second word onto another line. Below is sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/VM723/

```
    .BtnSize {
        width: 125px;
    }
    <input type="button" value="TestTestTest/&#10;FooFooFooFoo" class="BtnSize" />
```

Comment: Question has already been answered in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790896/muli-line-button-in-ie

Comment: You are correct, that thread answers my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button type="button">TestTestTest/&#10;FooFooFooFoo</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   .BtnSize {
        width: 125px;
        white-space:normal;
        word-break: break-all; 
    }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp